# How to pass the same index on a column for duplicate pairs on another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to give the same index for duplicates values on my `Dataframe`. Note that the index must be on a column

I've managed to find the duplicates and their respective position on the Dataframe. I don't know how to set values on the found duplicate pairs.

```py
def double_finder(dataframe, where: str):
    new_index = 10000 #new index start 
    df = dataframe[where]
    new_list = df.values.tolist()

    d = pd.DataFrame({"data": new_list})
    f = d.groupby("data").groups # this creates a dict class with the values 
                                 # of the Dataframe and their position 
                                 # on the Dataframe
```

so `new list` has the form of `['a-4', 'b-210', 'a-4', 'z-b', 'c-a', 'b-210']`
. The `f`'s outcome looks like this `"a-4": Int64Index: [0 , 2], "b-210": Int64Index: [1, 4], "z-b": Int64Index: [3]` etc.

I want to achieve something like this on my final `Dataframe`:

`index_col, data
 0, a-4
 1, b-210
 0, a-4
 2, z-b
 3, c-a
 1, b-210`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) and assign to `index`:

```
new_list = ['a-4', 'b-210', 'a-4', 'z-b', 'c-a', 'b-210']
d = pd.DataFrame({"data": new_list})
d.index = pd.factorize(d['data'])[0]
print (d)
    data
0    a-4
1  b-210
0    a-4
2    z-b
3    c-a
1  b-210
```

If need new column:

```
new_list = ['a-4', 'b-210', 'a-4', 'z-b', 'c-a', 'b-210']
d = pd.DataFrame({'new':pd.factorize(new_list)[0] ,"data": new_list})
print (d)
   new   data
0    0    a-4
1    1  b-210
2    0    a-4
3    2    z-b
4    3    c-a
5    1  b-210
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I also did `d.reset_index()' to get my column and replace it in my `Dataframe`.